# Upload file to volley as request body?

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to upload a file as body with PUT request to server of `Content-Type:application/octet-stream` .
I have searched a lot and all the examples consists of multipart but none of it contains how to put the byte to server.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You should use multipart request in order to upload a file using Volley. You can implement your own functions or use a ready library. Here is a good one I used in a project before [multipart-android](https://github.com/javierugarte/multipart-android)